# CakePHP 4.1.1. The beforeSave callback must return false or EntityInterface instance

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I’m using CakePHP 4.1.1. I have been translating some plugins since version 3.9. Having trouble with the beforeSave callback.

When the condition shown in the image is met:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCkk1.png)

Gives an error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuyzU.png)

RuntimeException throws the message:

> The beforeSave callback must return false or EntityInterface instance. Got boolean instead.

A little confused. I ask for advice. Thank.

Comment: Looking at the CakePHP code, it seems that null, false and EntityInterface should all be handled fine. The code you've highlighted should implicitly return null, I believe. Why do you think it's that particular `beforeSave` callback that's causing the problem? Is there maybe some other `beforeSave` which is also being called, and returning `true`, which is not allowed?

Comment: I have defined this callback with the exception method.

The logic in the indicated code is as follows: The file being loaded is being checked. If the file does not load, further operations with the file should be interrupted at the BeforSave stage.

There are no problems uploading the file.

https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage/blob/c6233c1af258442b4d00375d2bc47f5db6806688/src/Model/Behavior/FileStorageBehavior.php#L95

Comment: What I'm saying is that the code you've shown (side note, you are likely to get more responses if you include the actual code here; don't link to it, and don't use screen shots) seems like it should be fine, and the problem may lie in some other code, maybe something you're not even considering. Check whether there's some *other* `beforeSave` callback being invoked when there's a problem.